# std::distance in std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I wanted to solve the problem "TwoSum" with the help of the HashSet. When I try to post the solution, it fails in the second case with the answer [2,0] [image]

However, when I try to do the same thing шт IDE it returns me the right answer[image]

Code:

```
std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        std::unordered_set<int> mp;
        for (auto i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) 
        {
            if (auto it = mp.find(target - nums[i]); it == mp.end()) 
            {
            mp.emplace(nums[i]);
            }
            else 
            {
                return {static_cast<int>(std::distance(mp.begin(), it)), i };
            }
        }
    return {};
    }
```

Comment: *What is wrong with my solution?* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: `mp` is an unordered_set, but you are assuming elements will be in the same order you inserted them.  Your `std::distance` is going to return random numbers.  Why do you need it, anyway?  Why not just search the list you have?

Comment: Pro tip, do NOT mention leetcode but phrase youre question in terms of a pure C++ problem (which in this case it is). Leetcode is normally really considered harmful because so many bad coding practices are used by people who didn't learn C++ in the first place. So there is a tendency by expeprienced programmers to immediately downvote at the mere mentioning of leetcode. Admittedly you at least seem to be trying to use the standard library to good effect ;)

Comment: You didn't tell us what the code is supposed to do, so how how would we know what is wrong?

Comment: the code is supposed to find if is it possible to receive a target with adding elements of array

Comment: Comments can disappear forever at any time, so let me rephrase. **The question** doesn't tell us what the code is supposed to do, so how would we know what is wrong? *It might also be useful to [edit] in an explanation of why you think the code should do what it is supposed to do.*

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but
> organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends
> entirely on the hash of its value.

This means that the order of elements stored in `std::unordered_set` is **not guaranteed to be the same** as insertion order! So you can't expect that `std::distance` gives you the index of element in the original array.

To keep access to indices of values you can use `std::unorderd_map`:

```cpp
std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {

        if (auto it = mp.find(target - nums[i]); it == mp.end())
        {
            mp[nums[i]] = i;
        }
        else
        {
            return {it->second, i};
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> hashtable;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            auto it = hashtable.find(target - nums[i]);
            if (it != hashtable.end()) {
                return {it->second, i};
            }
            hashtable[nums[i]] = i;
        }
        return {};
    }
};
```

Link：https://leetcode.cn/problems/two-sum/solutions/434597/liang-shu-zhi-he-by-leetcode-solution/

Answer (score -2):

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n = nums.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                    return {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
        return {};
    }
}
```

This comes from Leetcode China ，Official Explanation

Comment: this is solution with O(n^2) complexity in O(N) solutions there is hashmap

Comment: Yeah, why not raise the complexity by many magnitudes for no reason when we can solve it efficiently.